# Can Firebase be integrated with Stormpath?

Tags: firebase, stormpath

Could a Firebase application be integrated with Stormpath as a custom authentication provider ?

Comment: Probably can. Did you have a look at the respective docs? https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/custom.html and https://docs.stormpath.com/home/

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure due to Secure Token generation for Firebase. I don't know wheter Stormpath could generate that token with required information or not.

Comment: https://stormpath.com/blog/jwt-the-right-way/ and Looks like it: see https://stormpath.com/blog/build-api-restify-stormpath/

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question: yes.

I'll assume that you want to store your user accounts in Stormpath, and want to use Firebase for everything else. If that's the case, you could do something like this:

1. Authenticate to Stormpath.
2. On success, authenticate to Firebase with a JWT (*code sample below*).
3. Grab whatever information you need out of Firebase (with their user security in place for the data).

This would allow you to use both systems nicely together =)

```
var FirebaseTokenGenerator = require("firebase-token-generator");
var tokenGenerator = new FirebaseTokenGenerator("<YOUR_FIREBASE_SECRET>");
var token = tokenGenerator.createToken({
  uid: "1",

  // the fields below are taken from your Stormpath Account model, and are
  // being added to your firebase JWT
  customData: req.user.customData,
  email: req.user.email,
  givenName: req.user.givenName,
  surname: req.user.surname,
});
```

Here are some useful reading resources:

- https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/custom.html
- https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/password.html

This would work great with something like the Express-Stormpath library: https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/

Comment: That's really helpful. However, my concern is about placing FIREBASE_SECRET in a .js file, once that script to generate token is in a javascript file that'll be deployed on firebase and eventually loaded on browser. The same goes to stormpath secret used to communicate with Stormpath in order do authenticate users. Stormpath secret will likely be placed in simple js file deployed on firebase.

Comment: This would only be safe to run on the server-side.

Comment: Sure. That's why I don't think Firebase as backend could be integrated to Stormpath.

Comment: @blackjack - There are legitimate use-cases for integrating Firebase with Stormpath. We keep all our non-sensitive, realtime data in Firebase and all our sensitive customer data in a separate encrypted DB. We rely on Stormpath for user Authentication for both services. Sure Firebase promotes itself towards systems without a backend, but there are still myriad benefits to using Firebase, even when you are running your own server.